# Are online mortgage lenders as good as local brick-and-mortar ones?

Tags: mortgage

Are the online lenders responsive and helpful?  Lately it's been hard to get anyone on the phone though I suspect that's due to refi's because of the very low rates.

Answer (score 1):

I had a pretty good experience with Lending Tree, although they are a mortgage broker, not a lender themselves.

Answer (score 1):

At least five of my co-workers are currently re-financing through [Amerisave](http://www.amerisave.com/).  Four have had a wonderful experience.  The fifth has been dealing with a representative who constantly misunderstands him, asks for duplicate paperwork, and is in general fairly annoying to deal with.  He is willing to go through the hassle because he found the lowest rates through them.  All five co-workers recommend Amerisave despite this one co-worker's difficulties.

Another person I know has refinanced through [mortgagefool.com](http://mortgagefool.com) twice with good results.

In general I think online lenders are like brick and mortar lenders in that some will be good, some will be not-so-good.